# Database Normalization

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I've been given the task of normalizing this set of data:

```
COURSE=(CourseID, CourseName, CourseDuration, CourseFee{
    DelegateID, DelegateName, DelegateAddress, EventID, EventName, VenueID, VenueName, VenuePrice, BookingID, BookingType, BookingDate
})
```

The scenario is an IT company that runs short training courses at various hotels around the country, each event being hosted by one or more presenters (hence the BookingType - either Delegate or Presenter, if Presenter then no booking charge). An event is just an instance of a course running at a particular venue. VenuePrice refers to the cost for optional bed and breakfast at the hotel venue for the intervening nights

Here is what I have come up with for 3NF:

```
COURSE=(CourseID, CourseName, CourseDuration, CourseFee)  
DELEGATE=(DelegateID, DelegateName, DelegateAddress)  
EVENT=(EventID, VenueID*, CourseID*, EventName, EventDate)  
BOOKING=(BookingID, DelegateID*, EventID*, BookingDate, BookingType)  
VENUE=(VenueID, VenueName, VenuePrice)
```

I'd like to know if this is at all accurate, and if not, perhaps a guiding hand in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: homework? I think you figured it out... so there is nothing to say actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On what basis do you think that is in 3NF ?

Let's take a really simple example, `Course`.  Where exactly if he Functional Dependency, on what key ? How can `CourseName` be dependent on `CourseId`, when `CourseDuration` and `CourseFee` are dependent on `CourseName` ?

Same with the rest of the tables; `Event` being a little more complex, has a few more errors.

You cannot normalise, or achieve 3NF, when your starting point is to stick an `ID` on everything that moves.

No.  First normalise the **data**.  Achieve 3NF. I can understand a `CourseCode` or `ShortName` as something the user may use to identify course, but no `Id`.

After that, if and only if you need to, **add** an `Id` column and the **additional** index.